# Count average points per 'Match' in Python Django

Tags: python, sql, database, django

Say I have these two models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...

class Player(models.Model):
    match=models.ForeignKey(Match)
    points=models.IntegerField()
```

I want to calculate the average points per match, meaning I need sum the points of all players, then divide it by the count of matches. I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this efficiently in Django.

I've tried Googling, and searching StackOverflow, but I am having a hard time figuring out what terms I should be looking for in the first place.

```
match = Match.objects.annotate(total_points=Sum('player__points'))
```

match[0].total_points now returns the total points of one match, I need to sum total_points of every match and divide it by the total matches.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) to sum the total number of points, [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) to find the number of matches,  then divide in python to get the average number of points per match.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total_points = Player.objects.aggregate(Sum('points'))['points__sum']
num_matches = Match.objects.count()
average_points_per_match = total_points / num_matches
```

Comment: Heh, I am so dumb. I was painstakingly looking for a solution to do the whole calculation in a single query that I was completely oblivious to the most obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved more efficiently using one query as follows

```
from django.db.models import Avg
result = Match.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('score'))

result
{'score__avg': 4.012987012987013}
```

I found this question whilst trying to achieve a similar thing, but also wanted to know how many matches the average score was based upon.  Which I eventually solved as follows.

```
result = Match.objects.all().annotate(num_matches=Count('id')).aggregate(Avg('score'), Sum('num_matches'))

result
{'num_matches__sum': 77, 'score__avg': 4.012987012987013}
```